# Export data to excel

Tags: list-manipulation, export, data, dataset

If I have the following data of x and y:

data=https://pastebin.com/LRjLMfcr

How can I export data to excel to have the data in columns of x and y for each data set contained in the same tab, rather than in different tabs?. Also, how can I give the excel file a name?

I have tried: `Export["name.xls", data]` but it gives me all the data in different excel tabs

Thank you!

Comment: That data has dimensions `{8, 361, 2}` which is why you get 8 tabs. Try `Export["data.xls", data // Flatten[#, 1] &]`.

Comment: "how can I give the excel file a name?" It is not clear what you mean by this. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will go with my best interpretation of the OP's explanation. The following column repeats in all data sets. This will be the first column.

```
xdata = data[[1, All, 1]];
```

Other columns will be added and placed side by side resulting in a dimension of {361,9} for the new data.

```
ydata = Table[data[[i, All, 2]], {i, 1, Dimensions[data][[1]]}];

datainCols = Transpose[Join[{xdata}, ydata]];

Export["C:\\test2.xls", datainCols]
```

Few rows are shown here.

[image]